# Wordpress Background (Mobile) Web Authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress, authentication, mobile

I'm building an iPhone app that, in part, allows the user to log in to, pull data, and post data back to a Wordpress site (more specifically, Buddypress).  One way I'm considering approaching this problem is to use a series of UIWebViews to display the mobile-themed version of the site.

Ideally, I want the user to be able to, upon first-launch of the app, input their username and password, and then never have to do it again (functionally similar to tons of other social apps out there, like Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

Here's my question - obviously it is easy to store the user's login credentials, but how do I, in the background, establish an authenticated and persistant session with those credentials each time the app opens, so for the user, they are never presented with a login screen again, and can just use the app like normal?

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses XMLRPC to authenticate. You can, on top of the API given, write your own codes to store credentials. Persistent session can then be made.

Read this FAQ : [XML-RPC Support for WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)

Comment: I know that WordPress uses XML-RPC, and that I can make calls to XML-RPC with credentials to get data returned back.  But if I use UIWebViews?  Can I still use XML-RPC?  The UIWebViews just load up the mobile version of WordPress, and normally brings up the web login screen.  Is there a way to "login" before loading the web views so the user is already logged in?

Comment: For full layout customizations, you'd better not using UIWebView, as it is only an embedded browser. Try to load WordPress data via XML-RPC and show it in customized view, say UITableView.

Comment: So, basically, the answer to my question is that it is not possible to silently authenticate in the UIWebView in the background, and to just use XML-RPC instead and build out custom interfaces?